# Rails 3.1 Post/Comment model for blog -- How to submit comments via ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ujs

I'm trying to learn about using remote forms and using the example of an app where the Post model has_many Comments.

Assuming i have used the generic rails scaffolding to create/setup the post/comment model, controllers, default views, routes, etc, -- what should my `app/views/posts/show.html` look like?

Specific i am confused about:

1. Where should the comment form post to?
2. What parameters should be included?
3. Do i NEED to use a hidden attribute such as `f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id`

Thank you!

Comment: Check out railscasts.com, I'm sure there are some useful screencasts about this on there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your post has_many comments...

routes.rb (Nested Resources)

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

In your comments_controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.comment.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
  ...
end
```

In the form:

```
=form_for [@post, @comment], :remote => true do |f|
  =f.text_field :text
  =f.submit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jesse.  Posting the form_for along with the nested routes helped clarify where i was going wrong.